# How to enable spell check for words with less than 4 letters in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have CKEditor 4, using SCAYT spell check. It works fine for words 4 letters or longer, but it doesn't detect misspells of shorter words. Is there any way to turn on spell check for 2-3 letter words?

Comment: Initially I was going to tell you to Google it.  But I just did and I haven't been able to find a single thing about if it can be adjusted.  One person was also complaining about this issue but got not response.  God Speed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`config.scayt_minWordLength`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-scayt_minWordLength) configuration option. I vaguely remember there might be some performance implications for lowering the default settings, so try it out and see what works for you.

Comment: that is the config to set min Work length, however it works starting with CKEditor version 4.5 beta (see https://github.com/WebSpellChecker/ckeditor-plugin-scayt/issues/96). Unfortunately I have version 4.4 and the config doesn't change the default behavior

Comment: Then it's a bug which will be fixed in the next release. CKEditor 4.5 should be out next week or the week after at the latest. Sorry about any inconvenience caused!